# Avoid extra NULL rows from case statement in new columns

Tags: sql, null, case, rdbms

Below is the expected result and we want to avoid the nulls from actual result from query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE STAGING.Test1  (
    TYPE_ID INTEGER,
    TYPE INTEGER,
    Value Varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO STAGING.Test1 VALUES
(1,100,'complete'),
(1,200,'2022/12/12'),
(1,300,'Y'),
(2,100,'pending'),
(2,200,'2021/11/11'),
(2,300,'N')


SELECT TYPE_ID
,CASE WHEN TYPE = 100 Then Value END AS STATUS 
,CASE WHEN TYPE = 200 Then Value END AS DATE 
,CASE WHEN TYPE = 300 Then Value END AS FLAg 
 FROM STAGING.Test1
```

Actual Result

| TYPE_ID | STATUS | DATE | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | complete | null | null |
| 1 | null | 12/12/2022 | null |
| 1 | null | null | Y |
| 2 | pending | null | null |
| 2 | null | 11/11/2021 | null |
| 2 | null | null | N |

Expected result

| TYPE_ID | STATUS | DATE | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | complete | 12/12/2022 | Y |
| 2 | pending | 11/11/2021 | N |

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tezS1.png)

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. I've removed the conflicting tags. Please (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: What if there is no register with date, status or flag? Can you have multiple values for the same (id, type)?

Comment: You aren't aggregating in your query, so you're going to get a row in your result for every row in your table. Try using `max` around each of your case statements.

Comment: Also, please don't use images to for sample data/desired results (or anything else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT TYPE_ID
,MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 100 Then Value END) AS STATUS 
,MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 200 Then Value END) AS DATE 
,MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 300 Then Value END) AS FLAg 
 FROM Test1
GROUP BY  TYPE_ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6DRtVmEG) on SQL Server.